# Commentless downvotes

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, down-votes

Is there a policy to encourage people to make comments when they give downvotes? Commentless downvotes do very little to improve the site. If something is wrong, you should explain what about it is wrong.

Comment: There's been a [bunch](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes) [of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59736/) [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66020/) [of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86223/) this topic on meta.SO.

Comment: @Isaac, mot of what you link to is suggestions that the software encourage comments (by assigning/removing reputation depending on whether comments are left), whereas this question (unless I'm reading it wrong) seems to be about a best-practices policy encouraging comments without any software implementation. Such a policy needn't be common to all the SE sites AFAICT.

Comment: @msh210 Agreed on both points. That's why I linked to these discussions as relevant data rather than submitting them as an answer, as if this question was resolved already.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is already such a rule in [the FAQ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq) (and also in [the old FAQ](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23)):

> If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong.

Answer (score 9):

> Commentless downvotes do very little to improve the site.

Oh, but you're wrong! Voting is *at least* - and probably *more* - important than commenting when it comes to improving the quality of the information presented by the site. Up-voted questions are given more visibility, while down-voted questions are given less. Up-voted answers display (by default) near the top of the list under their question, while down-voted answers display near the bottom. And users with a history of posting poor questions or answers can be restricted from further participation.

Comments... Hmm. Carefully-crafted constructive criticism can motivate a receptive author to improve their post. But not all voters are sufficiently diplomatic, nor all authors sufficiently receptive of criticism, to make this ideal outcome a reality. And not all down-votes *require* comments: the criterion for down-voting is simply that the reader did not find the answer "useful" - this doesn't necessarily indicate a problem that needs to be *stated* in a comment, any more than a comment noting an answer's usefulness needs to be coupled with an up-vote.

Ultimately, comments and votes are two different forms of communication, with different intended uses and different audiences. The system does encourage you to leave a comment when down-voting, but if you don't have anything worth saying, then... don't say it.

Comment: +1 for evening the playing field. The question should apply equally to up-voting, as your answer implies.

Comment: -1, and I'll do one better: I'll explain. I believe the _goal_ of the SE network is to provide useful information to anybody looking for it.  The _means_ to that goal is to encourage users to contribute useful content, and modify existing content so that it becomes (more) useful. Commentless downvoting can advance the **immediate** _goal_ (by ensuring that the content most useful to the most people rises and gets noticed), but it shoots the **overall** *means* in the foot (because it makes it harder to improve that content, and the author cannot correct himself for the future).

Comment: -1, and I'll add -- Explaining a down vote helps avoid causing the poster to feel that the down vote was a prejudicial vote having nothing to do with the content, or reflects the view of someone who has serious theological differences with normative Judaism.  Causing such speculation is not helpful to our souls, as well as hurtful or unhelpful to the quality of the answers and questions on the site.

Comment: Hmmm 9 downvotes and only two explanations for those downvotes.

Comment: @Daniel ...and twelve upvotes on those comments.

Comment: @Daniel maybe several downvoters are doing so for the same reason and no need for lots of "me too" comments

Comment: I upvoted this answer. Do you REALLY need to know why??? (Careful - you may get what you ask for :-)

Comment: @HodofHod: I just accidentally posted a duplicate of this question because your reasoning of 6-1/2 years ago struck me as obvious.

Comment: I see that I already upvoted this answer a while ago, and boy, am I happy that in about 3 years, no one has asked me why. But, while I find good constructive comments useful (though, not always helpful, admittedly,) to me, the bottom line is this is just another web site. (Moderators, don't get offended by that!) We're all anonymous, here (though I wouldn't mind meeting a few of you to tell you what I **really** think ;-) My point is - if someone wants to vote either positive or negative, I'm not emotionally attached to a cyber-number in any significant way. I can't figure why anyone would be.