# Moderators control of downvotes

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes

I got a down vote for my question here [Interfaith debates](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71259/6886)
and my answer here
[Is God Praiseworthy?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71252/6886)

By neither place were there any negative comments, to tell me what's wrong or how I should improve. So I was wondering what kind of control or access do moderators have with downvotes. Can they see who downvoted to send them a message to explain it? Can they change down votes if someone were to go on a random downvoting rampage, or would they be able to block the user from doing such?

Comment: I recommend not getting too hung up on a single vote. Try to write posts that are high-quality and useful enough that the upvotes overwhelm the odd downvote.

Comment: @IsaacMoses You're right, it doesn't matter that much. The question was also partially out of curiosity rather than solely about my posts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moderators cannot see who downvoted a post. Note [not all downvotes need to come with explanations](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/146/759), though they are often nice and hopefully constructive.

There are automatic systems in place to remove votes which seem [fraudulent or inappropriate](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed).