# What should our scope text be?

Tags: discussion, scope, faq-content, 7-essential-metas

*(This is a spin-off of [this question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/what-should-our-faq-material-contain-how-should-we-describe-the-scope-of-this) which was probably too broad.)*

The beginning of our [FAQ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq) currently reads (bolding mine):

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Jewish Life and Learning - Stack Exchange is for **students and teachers of Jewish law and tradition**.

I bolded the phrase that we'd like to come up automatically in different places when the site needs to remind someone what the scope is. Perhaps most prominently, every new visitor to the site sees the following notification:

> Welcome to Q&A for students and teachers of Jewish law and tradition — check out the [FAQ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq)!

I've had a new visitor complain to me that this sounds too formal and that it could turn away people who don't see themselves as either students or teachers.

Another possibility is the definition we used during the Commitment phase on our [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435?phase=commitment):

> ... for people who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more.

The idea behind this formulation, which I explained in detail in the comments on the proposal, is that it describes the core expert group we're targeting - people who think about Judaism all the time because they consider it binding and live their lives by it - while also opening the door to people with curiosity but less Jewish involvement.

Should we keep the current phrasing? Should we come up with something new? Answers that include concrete phrasing proposals will be most appreciated.

Don't forget: We want every new visitor to see these words, so it's pretty important to make sure they leave the right impression.

Comment: Regarding the concern of the new visitor: Are there any firsthand data indicating repulsion of potential users caused by this line?

Comment: @WAF We'd have to do a survey or a focus group or something to get that. I think we'll just have to go by the intuition and judgement of the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like

> for people who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more

from the proposal (though frankly I'd replace *people* with *those*).

Comment: So replace it. This is your answer.

Comment: Why do you prefer "those" to "people"?

Comment: @IsaacMoses re "Why...": Because (and I don't know the words to explain this right, so bear with me) _those_ is less strong a word. _People_ calls more attention to itself, is more noticeable, and, therefore, pulls more attention away from the more important part of the line. At least, that's my impression. Re "So replace...": Well, I _did_ replace it, by mentioning the replacement. As I was responding to the _people_ version, I specified mine as a diff of that one.

Comment: I've implemented this answer (using "those") in the FAQ.

Comment: Followup question: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/100966