# Lists of in- and out-of-scope topics for the FAQ

Tags: discussion, scope, faq-content, 7-essential-metas

Many other SE sites have, in their FAQ, right below the [scope line](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177/what-should-our-scope-text-be), a list of topics considered in-scope and sometimes also a list of topics considered out-of-scope.

For example, the beginning of [money.SE's FAQ](https://money.stackexchange.com/faq) reads:

> ### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Personal Finance and Money - Stack Exchange is for people who want to be financially literate, find ways to save money, minimize taxes, invest wisely, plan for retirement, etc. Also for financially-savvy amateurs, DIY-investors & personal finance pros.
>
> If you have a question about:
>
> - Personal investing and asset allocation
> - The financial aspects of homebuying
> - Best practices for saving for retirement, education, and other goals
> - Strategies for creating and sticking to a budget
> - Strategies for earning and saving more money
>
> ...then you've come to the right place - we want to help you!
>
> #### What about other money and finance related questions?
>
> Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:
>
> - Questions about corporate or government finance
> - Academic questions about economics or questions about economics that have no bearing on personal finance
> - Argumentative questions about personal finance or government policy
> - Requests for specific buy/sell advice; e.g. "should I sell X?" or "should I buy Y?" or "will X continue to go up?"

What should go in our "in" and "out" lists?

Neither of the following sources is binding, but both could provide inspiration:

- Our existing collection of [questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions)
- The example questions voted on- and off-topic on our [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/jewish-life-and-learning?phase=definition#tab-top)

Comment: Made canonical and part of the [meta-tag:faq] at http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a question about...

- Jewish law or practice (what to do or why)

  - [How many slices are required to make you responsible to wash on Pizza?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1818)
  - [Why is it OK to have a sermon right before Kaddish of Musaf?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3383)
  - [Can you recommend an alternative outer talit bag?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119)
- Jewish philosophy

  - [Does one have to take a Midrash/Aggadah literally?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4037)
- a Jewish text (explaining a passage)

  - ["The drinking was according to doctrine, no forcing." — Forcing to drink, or forcing to stop drinking?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6346)
  - [Help with Tosfot "v'HaAmar R. Yochanan" on Brachot 5b](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6994)
- history of Jewish law or of Jewish life

  - [Are there other extant Chabad groups besides Chabad-Lubavitch?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7915)
  - [When/how was the controversy regarding stainless-steel blades for shechitah resolved?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6732)
- language used in Jewish life and learning

  - [Why is הושיעה Mileel whereas הצליחה is Milra?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8182)
- general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Jewish life and learning

  - [Why is the latest time for candle lighting about a week after the longest day?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2326)
  - [What's the leading medical explanation for the "woman whose husbands keep dying" ("katlanit") phenomenon?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6542)

... then you've come to the right place. Please, [ask away](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!

On the other hand, questions unrelated to Jewish life and learning, even if they are about...

- other religions

  - [What does Islam (officially) think about Jews? What do mainstream Muslims think about Jews?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22607)
- Hebrew language

  - [Can anybody translate this Hebrew tattoo for me?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7859)
- Jews, Jewish history, and Israel

  - [Who devised Israel's current parliamentary system?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22479)
  - [Who was responsible for the deaths in the flotilla incident off Israel's coast?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22439)
  - [How many Jewish members are there in the U.S. Congress?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22476)
  - [How did the Jews get to control all the banks and news media?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23248)
  - [In which way antisemitic attitudes against Jews began to become more extreme under the Nazi regime?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8045)

... are generally off-topic.

Comment: I disagree with some here. Unless there is precedence for closing these questions, I think Jewish history should be ontopic. Also, questions about the Hebrew language (e.g. etymological) and about Israel are very much related to Jewish life!  (with the exceptions of translations, politics, etc.)

Comment: @AviD: For some small amount of precedent, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7859 (Hebrew) and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8045 (history).

Comment: Well the first is a translation question, which I agreed is off topic; the second is only indirectly about jewish history, anyway. Though your comment and @Isaac's do seem to be a bit more globally exclusive of history questions, I think it really depends a lot on the context. E.g. would questions on the history of chassidut be offtopic, too? Zionism? etc. Perhaps that should be a different question...

Comment: @AviD: I'm trying to understand why you consider an etymology question more on-topic/in-scope than a translation question. I agree it's a better question (translation questions are very simple and can often — though certainly not always — be looked up [elsewhere](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9), while etymology questions can be complex and most often can't be looked up). But I don't get why it's more _on-topic_.

Comment: @msh210, I guess it's because one is *about* the language, whereas the other is *in* the language (so to speak). I think it's also parallel to the difference between "What does this [passuk|mishna|rashi|etc] mean", as opposed to asking a specific difficulty with what it says. (I don't think I'm explaining that well... ) Also it seemed that this was the precedent here...

Comment: @AviD - Would you be OK with these three entries if the word "when were inserted before the word "unrelated"?

Comment: I think it might be useful to follow each off-topic entry with an "e.g."

Comment: @IsaacMoses, re "when": that was my intent. Done.

Comment: @msh210 I realized that that was your intent. I'm just wondering if @AviD did, and whether part of his disagreement comes from misunderstanding of your intent.

Comment: @Isaac, those are indeed good examples that I agree with. I think there is a fine line on some of the topics - I'm thinking it might have to do with the difference between "history of jews" as opposed to "jewish history"... or maybe better "history of the jewish nation" - where the first I agree is offtopic, whereas something like the 2nd/3rd should be ontopic.

Comment: In any event, @msh210, I think the latest edit is very good. The line "if unrelated to..." is a bit amorphous, though - it's not very explanatory or definitive. (It's just saying "if its not ontopic...")

Comment: @AviD Are you OK with the topic lists here, as currently formulated, or are there more from your list that you'd prefer to include?

Comment: @msh210 I suggest reducing to exactly one example question per topic, except in the last, catch-all one. I also suggest using only links from within J.SE for on-topic examples.

Comment: @Isaac, if this to be a complete list (as opposed to an abridged version), then I would say yes. But I think first there should be more community feedback?

Comment: @AviD Halevai! http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-can-we-get-more-people-involved-in-meta-discussions

Comment: @Isaac, also please take into account that on Area51, there were several different Judaism-related proposals, that all got wrapped up into this one. So to some extent, these should also be serviced (Not saying they aren't, I dont remember all of them...)

Comment: Btw, there are several language-related sites advancing in beta (I've seen German, Japanese...) Other than simplistic questions and translations, I don't know why Hebrew questions (i.e. questions about elements of the Hebrew language) are off topic, after all it is the Jewish language.

Comment: @AviD I'm pretty comfortable going with whatever data ended up in the JL&L proposal, and more importantly, with what the current community thinks would make sense. None of the other proposals ever really got traction, and anyone who was interested in them presumably contributed to the definition phase for our proposal when the others got closed.

Comment: I've added this to the FAQ.

Comment: ... on advice from mods of other sites, I've taken out the lists of examples for now, to make the FAQ look less cluttered. If you think the examples are important, we can possibly roll back the edit.

Comment: Made canonical and part of the [meta-tag:faq] at http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473.

Answer (score 3):

Incomplete list.... :

### On topic:

- Halacha questions (i.e. what to do, and why) (all types and areas)
- Common minhagim (e.g. what is it, does it apply, etc)
- Textual sources for information or practice
- Jewish history (i.e. history of Jews, or of the Jewish nation)
- History of [some Jewish aspect] (e.g. a certain minhag, a Jewish proverb, names, etc...)
- Jewish philosophy
- Books / learning: e.g. Tanach, Mishna/Gemara, parshanim, etc. Specifically, explanation of some specific difficulty, or guidance in concepts etc.
- Hebrew etymology
- Israel environment and life
- Jewish foods?
- Jewish art/music
- How other disciplines and areas that bear directly on Jews and/or Judaism do ao

### Off topic:

- Other religions
- Politics
- Hebrew translations

---

These are not complete, but I think this is good to get started with.
I'm making this community-wiki, so feel free to add as needed!

Comment: Thanks very much for getting the ball rolling!