# Comparing judaism with psychological theories

Tags: discussion, scope

My question is if we can close questions asking for equivalences between Judaism and psychological theories as cognitive psychologies or other therapies, as questions asking about comparative religions. My opinion is that is the same category of questions.

Comment: Hmm can you provide an example? I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly you're describing

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/125586/are-the-rights-which-provide-basis-for-assertiveness-in-line-with-jewish-philoso    @double AA

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend applying a similar standard to the one proposed in the [highest-voted answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/858/2) to our original Meta question about comparative religion: If the question asks "What does Judaism think of X precept of this other system?", it's likely on-topic, but bear in mind the [quality issues](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/is-a-question-that-asks-what-does-judaism-think-of-x-possibly-off-topic) that can come with questions of that form. If the question is "compare and contrast Judaism's and this other system's approach to X," that requires expertise in the other system and is therefore likely off-topic unless the question includes all of the necessary information about the other system.

Comment: I think that to take an idea and examine if it's in the range or out of range of Judaism is almost impossible unless you have a halachic testing. And for most of the cases it's not halchically compatible

Comment: Thank you for the answer