# What topics are in- and out-of-scope on Mi Yodeya?

Tags: support, faq, scope

- What topics are in-scope on Mi Yodeya? Can I see some examples?
- What topics are out-of-scope on Mi Yodeya? Can I see some examples?
- Where can I discuss changing these guidelines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The community has generally accepted this as the canonical list of in- and out-of-scope topics on Mi Yodeya.

If you have a question about...

- Jewish law or practice (what to do or why)

  - [How many slices are required to make you responsible to wash on Pizza?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1818)
  - [Why is it OK to have a sermon right before Kaddish of Musaf?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3383)
  - [Can you recommend an alternative outer talit bag?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119)
- Jewish philosophy

  - [Does one have to take a Midrash/Aggadah literally?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4037)
- a Jewish text (explaining a passage)

  - ["The drinking was according to doctrine, no forcing." — Forcing to drink, or forcing to stop drinking?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6346)
  - [Help with Tosfot "v'HaAmar R. Yochanan" on Brachot 5b](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6994)
- history of Judaism

  - [Are there other extant Chabad groups besides Chabad-Lubavitch?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7915)
  - [When/how was the controversy regarding stainless-steel blades for shechitah resolved?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6732)
- language used in Judaism

  - [Why is הושיעה Mileel whereas הצליחה is Milra?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8182)
- general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Judaism

  - [Why is the latest time for candle lighting about a week after the longest day?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2326)
  - [What's the leading medical explanation for the "woman whose husbands keep dying" ("katlanit") phenomenon?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6542)

... then you've come to the right place. Please, [ask away](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!

On the other hand, questions unrelated to Judaism, even if they are about...

- other religions

  - [What does Islam (officially) think about Jews? What do mainstream Muslims think about Jews?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22607)
- Hebrew language

  - [Can anybody translate this Hebrew tattoo for me?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7859)
- Jews, Jewish history, and Israel

  - [Who devised Israel's current parliamentary system?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22479)
  - [Who was responsible for the deaths in the flotilla incident off Israel's coast?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22439)
  - [How many Jewish members are there in the U.S. Congress?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22476)
  - [How did the Jews get to control all the banks and news media?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23248)
  - [In which way antisemitic attitudes against Jews began to become more extreme under the Nazi regime?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8045)

... are generally off-topic.

---

Any requests to change standing site policy should be directed to [Mi Yodeya Meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). First, though, please see [the primary thread which led to formulation of the above material](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/178) and other questions with the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag.