# Holocaust etymology question migration

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

My question on the origins of the term "Holocaust" was migrated to another board.  That's fine, but why does migration have to close out a question from the Judaism board?  It would seem to be appropriate in both places.

Comment: Migration _usually_ means it is off topic on the source site.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/166155

Comment: @DoubleAA:  How was this subject off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

As [the FAQ list](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) explains, q.v., questions about Jewish history are off-topic on Mi Yodeya. In fact, a specific question [listed](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1474) as an example of an off-topic Jewish-history question is ["In which way antisemitic attitudes against Jews began to become more extreme under the Nazi regime?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8045).

Migration is simply closure as off-topic, with the added benefit of simultaneously asking the question elsewhere (instead of *only* closing it as off-topic).

Comment: The FAQ is contradictory.  Yes, it says questions about Jewish history are off-topic, but it also says: "If you have a question about...history of Jewish law or of Jewish life...then you've come to the right place."  Plus, there is a tag for History.  So which is it?

Comment: I don't see how my question related to the sample you provided.  The differences in the examples on on-topic history questions and off-topic history questions seem to be very arbitrary and hard to discern without being able to read the minds of the moderators.  The only common thread I can find is you don't want to talk about politics in modern-day Israel or the politics surrounding the Holocaust.

Comment: Followup to these comments: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1498