# Are scenario questions acceptable for asking?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Are hypothetical questions that are limited to a specific scenario valid for asking, even though the chances of the scenario actually occurring are very slim?

Comment: Similar: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3760

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The FAQ, elaborated [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473/3), says "questions about Jewish practice" are in-scope. I believe that means that the question must relate to the Jewish aspects of a practice, real or imagined. There are certainly non-deleted questions having to do with extremely specific and infrequent scenarios already on the site ([example](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30373/3)).

Elsewhere on meta, the guiding principle of stating the motivation for your question is recommended, as it helps give useful and informative answers. I would think it worthwhile to apply it in cases such as these to determine the goodness of a question. "I imagined this scenario" would not independently constitute a justifiable motivation, but "I imagined this scenario and expect that myself and people I know will one day occupy it" would.

(This was influenced partly by the discussion recently linked in Chat about [efficient sock pairing on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164379/165320).)

Comment: although also making certain parts more globally applicable is very often very helpful