# Are questions about Jewish culture (NOT religion-centric) in scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

This came up in a completely unrelated SE chat, with someone claiming that (unlike Christianity.SE being "about Christian doctrine and practice") Judaism.SE is "**about Jewish culture**".

My impression (perhaps incorrect) was that Judaism.SE had purely secular Jewish culture as out of scope, but I couldn't find anything explicitly stating so on Meta or in Help.

The best I found was : [What topics are in- and out-of-scope on Mi Yodeya?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/what-topics-are-in-and-out-of-scope-on-mi-yodeya?rq=1)

> "On the other hand, questions unrelated to Judaism, even if they are about......"
>   ".... Jews, Jewish history, and Israel "
>   ... ... are generally off-topic.

Examples of "purely secular Jewish culture" would be (stolen from @msh's answer):

> bagels and lox, borscht-belt comedians, Yiddish theater, kibbutz life, Fiddler on the Roof, and the Ladino language

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions about not Judaism but things generally considered "Jewish culture" — like [bagels and lox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Jewish_cuisine_dishes), [borscht-belt comedians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borscht_Belt), [Yiddish theater](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish_theatre), [kibbutz life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibbutz#Communal_life), [*Fiddler on the Roof*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_on_the_Roof_(film)), and [the Ladino language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaeo-Spanish) — are off-topic. (This could, perhaps, be clearer in [the list you link to](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1474), but is IMO covered by its terms.) Of course, questions about such topics that are *also* about Judaism may be on-topic.

But things about the culture of the Jewish religion (the culture of Jewish religious practice) — like [choosing a good bag for one's prayer garment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/119) and [what is good to send as *mishloach manos*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/301) — are on topic.

Comment: Thank you. In case it wasn't clear from the question, the first paragraph was what I was most interested in.