# Are questions on jokes, humour, fiction or pop culture allowed?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags, close-reasons, closed-questions

What's the point of [popular-culture](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popular-culture) and [humour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humour)/[humor](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humor) tags if my question [What's up with answering questions with questions in this joke from Family Guy?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96796/whats-up-with-answering-questions-with-questions-in-this-joke-from-family-guy) is going to be closed?

I don't see anything wrong with these tags. [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/55532/whats-up-with-churches-and-guitars-in-this-joke-from-the-big-bang-theory), [Maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popular-math) and [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry-in-fiction) SE (and i think [physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popular-science)) do it (regarding christianity SE, SORT OF. I'm [still discussing it](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7003/are-joke-questions-or-questions-about-fictional-events-on-topic)), and the tags on judaism SE are, well, not closed or anything.

---

**Edit**: God bless you all (or G-d or Yahweh or however you call God. Obviously I'm not Jewish) involved with this and [the other question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96796/whats-up-with-answering-questions-with-questions-in-this-joke-from-family-guy), in particular with my recent issues on Christianity SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't involved in closing your post, and I can't be sure what the precise reasoning of those who voted to close was. To my mind, the post is off-topic not because it makes reference to pop culture but because it is not about Judaism. Stereotypes about Jewish people are not in and of themselves about Judaism, though in some cases, there may be reason to believe that a particular stereotype is. Our canonical description of what's on-topic is [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and a previous Meta post specifically about Jewish culture is here: [Are questions about Jewish culture (NOT religion-centric) in scope?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1950/are-questions-about-jewish-culture-not-religion-centric-in-scope)

Regarding [popular-culture](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popular-culture) and [humor](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humor), if you look through the posts with those tags, you'll see numerous examples of well-received questions about Judaism that are related to or inspired by these subjects.

Comment: Isaac Moses, wait so 1 - the on-topicness of question depends on its answer? i mean for all i know there's something in the torah that advises certain questions to be answered with other questions. i mean, if that was the case, then the question would be on-topic right? or still not? i mean it's like asking a yes/no question and it's on-topic if the answer is yes but off-topic if the answer is no 2 - how are jewish people not related to judaism?

Comment: @BCLC Consider the following question about a Jewish person https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12146 As noted in this answer "in some cases, there may be reason to believe that a particular [thing] is [about Judiasm]". If there is such reason and it isn't obvious to eveyone, just state it explicitly. Same goes for that question on scifi.se and any question anywhere that wants to be asked here.

Comment: @BCLC 1) It could be on-topic to ask whether a stereotype about Jews is somehow based on Judaism. That would be a question about Judaism. 2) There are a lot of subjects related to Judaism (Jewish culture, Israeli politics, Hebrew language, other religions), but the standard for being on-topic is for the question to be about Judaism, not just related to it.

Comment: @DoubleAA LOL example i'm  not asking question about a person who happens to be jewish. is it not jewish culture? i think a better analogy is this thing from TBBT 'Isn't hypochondria a common idiosyncrasy of Jewish people?'

Comment: ' It could be on-topic to ask whether a stereotype about Jews is somehow based on Judaism. That would be a question about Judaism'  --> ok i will edit the post. thanks

Comment: @BCLC You asked in a comment "how are jewish people not related to judaism?" I tried to explain why the rules are worded the way they are

Comment: @DoubleAA oh, a nitpick. ok. i meant how are questions about jewish people as they relate to judaism not related to judaism? i believe i asked about jewish people as they related to judaism, and of course that's kind of what we're discussing.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Thanks for re-open. Why is the answer deleted?

Comment: @BCLC The existing answer did not address the on-topic version of the question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses God bless you (or G-d or Yahweh or however you call God. Obviously I'm not Jewish) and all involved with this and [the other question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96796/whats-up-with-answering-questions-with-questions-in-this-joke-from-family-guy), in particular with my recent issues on Christianity SE.

Comment: Isaac Moses♦, why doesn't the answer just become communitywiki?

Comment: @BCLC I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Isaac Moses never mind; I posted an answer