# Are you aware of the Yiddish proposal?

Tags: discussion

A couple hours ago some posted a [Yiddish proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79092/yiddish) on Area51, suggesting the creation of a sister site specific to Yiddish on SE. Not sure if the content would be in scope here, or if it should be separate.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know -- I wasn't aware, and as the answer below says, pure-language questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I would like you to comment here. This user is fairly new on Mi Yodeya, and a first-time-poster on Meta. He just accepted an answer that you seem to read as confirming your opinion, whereas it is in fact opposite: your *only "pure-language"* vs Scimonster's *general "off topic"*. Maybe Scimonster has misread the scope text, [just  as I did](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2138/include-biblical-hebrew#comment8212_2140). We risk a user walking away with a confirmed wrong conclusion.

Comment: @NBZ I think it is clear that questions about Yiddish are not in scope here, but Jewish questions are, if the Jewish question includes some detail that is in Yiddish or Russian, or whatever, has no bearing.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like we're all on the same page, then: a question *about* Yiddish (or any other language) is off-topic, but a *Jewish* question that happens to *involve* or *arise from* something in another language is on-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definitely off topic for Mi Yodeya. Even Hebrew language questions are off topic, and that's a quite basic part of Judaism. Yiddish language is certainly off topic.

See [What topics are in- and out-of-scope on Mi Yodeya?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/what-topics-are-in-and-out-of-scope-on-mi-yodeya)

Comment: [Maybe we made the same mistake?](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2138/include-biblical-hebrew#comment8210_2140)

Answer (score 4):

It would overlap. Language questions pertaining to Jewish life are on-topic. Language questions that do not touch on Jewish life are off-topic, even if the language is Jewish, i.e. Hebrew, Yiddish, Ladino, "Yeshivish", etc.

Source:*

> I think "what does chulent mean?" is already on-topic if asked in the
>   context of Jewish life -- e.g. "I've heard of this Shabbat dish called
>   chulent; what exactly is that? Are there specific ingredients that are
>   always present?" would be fine. But while it involves Yiddish, it's
>   not really a Yiddish question, if that makes sense. –  Monica Cellio♦
>   Aug 28 at 20:01

---

<sup>* [This comment](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/include-jewish-languages#comment8215_2139) was made to a question that was deleted, and is therefore unavailable to most users.</sup>