# Are questions about the Hebrew language on-topic?

Tags: support, scope

There's been a proposal on Area51 for a [Hebrew Language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75348/hebrew-language) SE for a while now, but as it isn't open yet, is it appropriate to ask a question about the Hebrew language here?

Comment: Note our policy is independent of any other site's existence.

Answer (score 6):

Hebrew has the same status here as any other language. Questions related to Judaism are on topic, while questions not related to Judaism are not. If your Hebrew/English/Spanish/Russian/Latin/Arabic/etc. question is about something to with Judaism, then it's on topic.

"What does this word in my Jewish text mean?" = On topic.
"What does this word from a billboard mean?" = Off topic.

See more at [our canonical "scope" FAQ post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1474/759).