# Change "Jewish life and learning" to "Judaism" in the list of on-topic reasons

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope, help-center

[The Help Center](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) now says:

> If you have a question about...
>
> - Jewish law or practice (what to do or why)
>
>   Jewish philosophy
>
>   a Jewish text (explaining a passage)
>
>   history of <del>Jewish law or of Jewish life</del>
>
>   language used in <del>Jewish life and learning</del>
>
>   general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to <del>Jewish life and learning</del>
>
> ... ([examples](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473)) then you've come to the right place. Please, [ask away](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!
>
> On the other hand, questions unrelated to <del>Jewish life and learning</del>, even if they are about...
>
> - other religions
>
>   Hebrew language
>
>   Jews, Jewish history, and Israel
>
> ... ([examples](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473)) are generally off-topic.

Based on discussion in the comments to [an answer of Isaac's](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1499), in the comments to [an answer of mine](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1730) and in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/jll-judaism-and-on-topicness), including reasons discussed there, qq.v., I propose that we change that to:

> If you have a question about...
>
> - Jewish law or practice (what to do or why)
>
>   Jewish philosophy
>
>   a Jewish text (explaining a passage)
>
>   history of **Judaism**
>
>   language used in **Judaism**
>
>   general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to **Judaism**
>
> ... ([examples](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473)) then you've come to the right place. Please, [ask away](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!
>
> On the other hand, questions unrelated to **Judaism**, even if they are about...
>
> - other religions
>
>   Hebrew language
>
>   Jews, Jewish history, and Israel
>
> ... ([examples](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473)) are generally off-topic.

(Strikethroughs and boldfacing represent changes in the text and don't/won't appear in the Help Center.) I propose likewise that [the same changes](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1474/revisions) be made to the [expanded version](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1474) of that same list.

Please upvote/downvote this question depending as you agree/disagree with this proposal. Either way, please feel free to post tweaks, other versions, "the status quo is good", or the like as answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two weeks later, this question has five upvotes and no downvotes, so I've effected the changes it proposes.