# Parameters of Jews not Judaism

Tags: discussion, policy

Based on [Giving up ones life על קידוש ה׳ not to transgress גילוי עריות](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91636/9682):

What are the parameters of “Jews not Judaism”? While the above question could be greatly improved with a citation to Sanhedrin 74a, the question does boil down to looking for stories about Jews, which happens to relate to a particular Halacha. Or since it’s regarding a particular Halacha, is that enough to consider it “Jews as pertains to Judaism”?

Comment: Interestingly we have a tag for [story identification](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) I'm wondering if your question also applies to anything that's in that tag, as many of those stories are not about halacha or anything, they're just about finding sources for a story.

Comment: The question is about Judaism. I'm not sure what the doubt is, how one can read that question and not see that it's about Judaism. Yes, it's also about Jews, but so what?

Comment: @aBochur Note that just because we have a tag for something, doesn't mean it's not currently off topic. For example, PTIJ is off topic 11 months of the year, riddles are off topic but kept for legacy purposes, etc.

Comment: @Salmononius2 I assume that’s why it’s a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1498/2

Comment: @salmon We even have a tag for gentiles and non-jewish-holidays neither of which is inherently on topic!

Answer (score 7):

According to the [help center](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If you have a question about...
>
> - Jewish law or practice (what to do or why)
> - Jewish philosophy
> - a Jewish text (explaining a passage)
> - history of Judaism
> - language used in Judaism
> - general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Judaism
>
> ...
>   ([examples](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/what-topics-are-in-and-out-of-scope-on-mi-yodeya))
>   then you've come to the right place. Please, [ask away](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!

Asking for stories about Jews that concern a Jewish practice (giving up one's life על קידוש השם), seems to fall clearly within "history of Judaism."

Compare one of the other canonical history posts from the above meta post: [When/how was the controversy regarding stainless-steel blades for shechitah resolved?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6732/when-how-was-the-controversy-regarding-stainless-steel-blades-for-shechitah-reso)