# Are questions about Jewish family structures on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Recently I read [this article](https://verysmartbrothas.theroot.com/do-white-people-have-cousins-1820685828), which describes the flexible use of the word *cousin* in African-American and Latinx communities. It made me wonder whether, historically, Jewish communities have had similarly flexible family taxonomies. Would that be on-topic for this forum, and, if not, what would be a more appropriate place to ask?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you ask the question in a way which has direct relevance to Judaism itself, it would probably be off-topic. From the [Help Center](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> On the other hand, questions unrelated to Judaism, even if they are
>   about...
>
> - other religions
> - Hebrew language
> - Jews, Jewish history, and Israel
>
> ... ([examples](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/what-topics-are-in-and-out-of-scope-on-mi-yodeya)) are generally off-topic.

See [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178/lists-of-in-and-out-of-scope-topics-for-the-faq) as well.

The question might be considered on topic on one of the other [Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), such as [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) or [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: OK, how about "does halacha recognize ambiguous cousin relationships"?

Comment: That sounds like it is about Judaism. If you choose to ask it here, please make sure to provide enough details/explanations so that readers understand precisely what it is you want to know. If you just write  "does halacha recognize ambiguous cousin relationships?" it will probably get closed as "unclear what you're asking".