# Update the new user greetings to match the FAQ text

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, scope, faq-content

This request is for the StackExchange staff:

Could you please change the text in the new user greetings on the  side of the page from

> students and teachers of Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more.

to

> those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more.

to match the text in the FAQ, as chosen [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177/what-should-our-scope-text-be) as well as the text in the banner that shows at the top of the page for new users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done.

Comment: It's still not entirely consistent. The sidebar text is "students and teachers of Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more." It's closer, but not the same as the FAQ and new-user-banner text.

Comment: Now it is. Thanks.