# Request clarification on forum policy on Judaism

Tags: support, scope

My post on living a Jewish life in the USA was closed as not being Jewish enough: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98951/seeking-jewish-version-of-the-mid-20th-century-green-book-travel-guide-for-afric?noredirect=1#comment330071_98951

But there seems to be great inconsistency in how the standards for this forum are applied.  The following posts seem no more Jewish than the current post that was closed as not being Jewish enough (including one on non-Jews):
[Jewish Community in China Around WW2](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5940/jewish-community-in-china-around-ww2)
[Did Shuls in Europe display their countries' flags prior to the holocaust?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9283/did-shuls-in-europe-display-their-countries-flags-prior-to-the-holocaust)
[Do Jewish historians consider the destruction of Jerusalem in 70 CE on par with the Shoah/Holocaust?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88485/do-jewish-historians-consider-the-destruction-of-jerusalem-in-70-ce-on-par-with)
[The curse of cannibalism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/the-curse-of-cannibalism)
[Showing support for jewish community by publicly wearing a Kippa while not being jewish?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87579/showing-support-for-jewish-community-by-publicly-wearing-a-kippa-while-not-being/87581#87581)

I request clarification of the standards for this forum.

Answer (score 5):

The relevant policy here is this part of [our FAQ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> On the other hand, questions unrelated to Judaism, even if they are about...
>
> - other religions
> - Hebrew language
> - Jews, Jewish history, and Israel
>
> ... ([examples](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473)) are generally off-topic.

Being about the lives Jewish people does not, by itself, make a question on-topic. Being about Judaism does. For more clarification on this point, see the following prior Meta posts:

- [Are questions about Jewish culture (NOT religion-centric) in scope?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1950/are-questions-about-jewish-culture-not-religion-centric-in-scope)
- [FAQ says History is off-topic and on-topic](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/faq-says-history-is-off-topic-and-on-topic)

To address your examples:

- Your post about historical methods of responding to Antisemitism was about how Jews lived but not about Judaism, so it was appropriately closed.
- [Jewish Community in China Around WW2](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5940/jewish-community-in-china-around-ww2) , similarly, is about Jews surviving in Japan during the Holocaust, but not about Judaism. I just closed it.
- [Did Shuls in Europe display their countries' flags prior to the holocaust?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9283/did-shuls-in-europe-display-their-countries-flags-prior-to-the-holocaust) is about synagogue practice, which is an expression of and regulated by Judaism, so it looks on-topic to me.
- [Do Jewish historians consider the destruction of Jerusalem in 70 CE on par with the Shoah/Holocaust?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88485/do-jewish-historians-consider-the-destruction-of-jerusalem-in-70-ce-on-par-with) doesn't seem to me to clearly have anything to do with Judaism, *per se*. If the question were fleshed-out more, it might become clear that it's on-topic. I'm going to close it and request such fleshing-out if relevant.
- [The curse of cannibalism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/the-curse-of-cannibalism) is quite clearly about understanding a passage in the Torah, which is part of Judaism.
- [Showing support for jewish community by publicly wearing a Kippa while not being jewish?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87579/showing-support-for-jewish-community-by-publicly-wearing-a-kippa-while-not-being) asks about the religious appropriateness, under Judaism,  of appropriating a Judaism practice, so it's about Judaism.

Comment: The question on China had 274 views, 6 up votes, and  2 answers with 6 up votes, and was posted for 2+ years.  The question was well received and widely viewed.  Only now is the question of appropriateness of topic being considered.  Clearly there is inconsistent application of what I see as unclear and unnecessarily restrictive standards for content.  I feel that any topic that significantly impacts the lives of Jews as Jews is appropriate for this forum.  The questions you just closed show the standard as I stated it is often followed in this forum, rather than the standard as you state it.

Comment: @YehudaW Not every off-topic post always gets closed. In particular, the China post was posted in Feb. 2011, which was before this community [joined the standard Stack Exchange network](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1) and consequently [did](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23) [some](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q177) [early](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/178) work to sharpen our scope. I'm sure it's not the only old post that's off-topic and still open.

Comment: @YehudaW If you'd like to propose an alternative to our current scope policy, you are welcome to do so in a new Meta post. Such an effort will be most likely to be productive if you try to craft a clear, sharp statement of scope that Yodeyans can then then evaluate and debate.

Comment: @YehudaW By the way, even though you don't have 3,000 reputation so you can't vote to close a question, you still have the option to flag a question as off-topic which sends it to a queue where it can be reviewed by users who do have voting privileges. So if you see that the policy is not being upheld on a given question, you can help fix it that way.